# Is there a way to only have autocomplete for email addresses in your contact list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I am still using the very old Outlook 2007. When composing a new email, typing into any of the recipient fields invokes autocomplete with a list of matching emails. The problem is that it shows email addresses that I've since deleted from my contact list, so I want to prevent those addresses from showing up at all. It seems that there's a file `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.NK2` that stores addresses to be used for autocomplete. I just verified it by renaming it to `_Outlook.NK2` and all of the addresses in autocomplete disappeared. However, I still want Outlook to autocomplete for addresses in my contact list.

Is there a way to achieve this or do we just chalk it up to poor design on an outdated version of Outlook?

Comment: NK2 files are no longer used. Delete the NK2 file (move it somewhere) and let it rebuild to your new contacts.

Comment: @John That's essentially what I did as noted in my question by renaming the file. It recreated the file, but I wouldn't say it rebuilt anything as the autocomplete list was nuked entirely. I was hoping there was a way to have it always autocomplete for addresses in my contact list, ignoring the NK2 file directly